# Elemento <strong> retornando vazio - Htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Estou tentando obter o conteúdo de um texto strong do site submarino. Quando abro o site com navegador eu posso ver no código o conteúdo porém, usando HtmlAgilityPack o conteúdo retorna vazio.

Exemplo:

```
    HtmlNodeCollection produtos = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//article[@data-component='single-product']");
    foreach (HtmlNode produto in produtos)
    {
        produto.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='sale price']/strong").InnerText.Trim();
    }
```

Requisição da pagina

```
HtmlWeb WebGet = new HtmlWeb ();
HtmlDocument page = webGet.Load("http://busca.submarino.com.br/busca.php?q=eletrodomesticos+e+eletroportateis&page=1")
```

Eu preciso enviar POST, adicionar parametros no load ou outro método para obter o conteúdo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var uri = "http://busca.submarino.com.br/busca.php?q=eletrodomesticos+e+eletroportateis&page=1";
        webBrowserControl = new WebBrowser { ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true};

        //exemplo2
        webBrowserControl.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        webBrowserControl.Navigate(uri);

        waitTillLoad(this.webBrowserControl);

        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        var documentAsIHtmlDocument3 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)webBrowserControl.Document.DomDocument;
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(documentAsIHtmlDocument3.documentElement.outerHTML);
        doc.Load(sr);

        HtmlNodeCollection produtos = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//article[@data-component='single-product']");
        foreach (HtmlNode produto in produtos)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Preço: " + produto.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='sale price']/strong").InnerText.Trim());
        }
        Debug.Print("");
    }


    private void waitTillLoad(WebBrowser webBrControl)
    {
        WebBrowserReadyState loadStatus;
        int waittime = 100000;
        int counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            loadStatus = webBrControl.ReadyState;
            Application.DoEvents();
            if ((counter > waittime) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Uninitialized) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Loading) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Interactive))
            {
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }

        counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            loadStatus = webBrControl.ReadyState;
            Application.DoEvents();
            if (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete && webBrControl.IsBusy != true)
            {
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

**Retorno:**

[image: Resultado]

Realmente com o seu código o campo desejado não é retornado, porém, com o código acima foi possível realizar a operação desejada.

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado.

Comment: Rubens, tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso via console application?

Comment: Creio que não seja possível devido a seguinte dependência: using System.Windows.Forms;